# Prove the polynomial $P_a=X^5 + a$ is reducible over a field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

> Let $(K, +, \cdot)$ a finite field so that the polynomial $P=X^2-5$ is
> irreducible.
>
> Prove that:
>
> a) $1+1 \ne 0$
>
> b) The polynomial $P_a=X^5 + a$ is reducible $\forall a \in K$

---

a) This is the easy part.

Suppose $1+1=0$. Then $5=1$ therefore $P=(X-1)(X+1)$ contradiction.

b) I think the idea is to show the equation $x^5 + a=0$ has solutions $\forall a \in K$, but I failed to prove it.

Any hint for an elementary solution is appreciated.

Comment: For the second part, do you mean to find all such fields where this holds?

Comment: Your idea for part b) does not work: x^5=2 has no solution in F_11.

Comment: @MattB No, to prove it for all fields.

Comment: @user148212 Over $F_{11}$ the polynomial $P=X^2-5$ is reducible

Answer (score 3):

If $a=0$,we're done. So, suppose $a\in F^\times$.

Let $p=$char$ F$. Then, $F=\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$. If $k$ is even, then, $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}\subseteq F$. However, $X^2-5$ splits over $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$, as splitting field of a degree two polynomial is of degree two, and $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ is the only degree two extension of $\Bbb{F}_p$. Contradiction.

So, $k$ is odd. $x^2-5$ has no solution means $5$ is not a quadratic residue $\Bbb{F}_p$. Then, by the quadratic reciprocity law, $p$ is not a quadratic residue in $\Bbb{F}_5$. In particular $5\not\lvert p\pm 1$, so, $5\not\lvert p^k-1$. Choose a generator $g\in F^\times$. Let $-a=g^{m}$. As $5\not\lvert p^k-1$, $5$ divides one of $m,m+(p^k-1),m+2(p^k-1),m+3(p^k-1),m+4(p^k-1)$. Then, $g^\frac{m+b(p^k-1)}5$ is a root of $x^5+a$, as desired.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_{p^2} \subset \mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ if and only if $k$ is even.

Comment: You're right. Forcing $k$ to be odd is enough for the solution also. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, but I need an elementary solution.

Comment: Once you show that $5\nmid p^k-1$, you're done, because by group theory $b\mapsto b^5$ is an automorphism of $F^\times$.

Comment: @egreg Yes, there are multiple ways of finishing the argument after that. What about getting $5\not\lvert p-1$ from a more direct way, as OP requested.

Comment: @Emre Doesn't seem to lead to solution, I deleted it